# Chrome Extension to delete old cookies ( windows )

Tags: windows, google-chrome, caching, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to delete the old cookies only and keep those that have been used or renewed in the last x months.
All mechanisms including those of chrome extensions allow me to delete the newest cookies only.
Please don´t ask me why I want to do this.
Please don´t tell me it is not neccessary.
Please don´t suggest another browser or OS.

Comment: The API [doesn't expose](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/#type-Cookie) the modification date, so you'll have to write an external app that directly accesses the `Cookies` file or you'll have to rely on the expiration date exposed by the API and use chrome.cookies.getAll + filter + chrome.cookies.remove. FWIW, it's possible to track the modification date by defining a setter on document.cookie in [the MAIN world](/a/9517879), but it seems wasteful to me.